# Acceleration in Inertial reference frame.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

[image: Inertial Reference Frame]

The above figure represents the motion of a particle at P, where the position vector are represented by

$\vec{r_{p}}$ - position vector of the point P  with respect to the inertial frame.

$\vec{r_{o'}}$ - position vector of the intermediate reference frame wrt to the inertial.

$\vec{r_{p/o'}}$ - position vector of point P wrt to the intermediate reference frame.

$\omega = \omega_m $ - angular velocity about the intermediate reference frame

$\alpha$ - the angular acceleration about the intermediate reference frame

then the velocity and acceleration can be derived as follows.

$\vec{r_p}  = \vec{r_{o'}} + \vec{r_{p/o'}}$

The general material derivative for fixed reference frame is give as shown below.

$\dfrac{D ()}{Dt} =  \dfrac{d ()_{o'}}{d t} + \omega_m  \times  ()_{p/o'} + \dfrac{d ()_{p/o'}}{d t} $

So, the velocity of point P with respect to the inertial reference frame will be

$
\vec{v_{p}} = \vec{v_{o'}} + \omega_m \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} + \vec{v_{p/o'}}
$

and so, the acceleration is obtained by taking the first derivative,

$  \vec{a_p}  = \dfrac{D{\vec{v_{p}}}}{Dt} $

$ \qquad = \dfrac{D \vec{v_{o'}}}{Dt} + \dfrac{D (\omega \times \vec{r_{p/o'}})}{Dt} + \dfrac{D \vec{v_{p/o'}}}{Dt} $

$\qquad = \vec{a_{o'}} + \omega \times \vec{v_{o'}} + \dfrac{D(v_{o'})}{Dt}_{| Pure~translation}
 +\dfrac{D \omega}{Dt} \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} + \omega \times \dfrac{D \vec{r_{p/o'}}}{Dt} + \dfrac{D\vec{v_{p/o'}}}{Dt} $

$ \qquad = \vec{a_{o'}} + \omega \times \vec{v_{o'}} + \dfrac{D(v_{o'})}{Dt}_{| Pure~translation} 
+ \vec{\alpha} \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} + (\omega \times \omega) \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} + \dfrac{D \vec{\omega}}{Dt}_{|pure~translation} \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} +
\vec{\omega} \times \vec{v_{p/o'}} +\omega \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} ) + \omega\times \dfrac{D(\vec{r_{p/o'}})}{Dt}_{|pure~ translation} +
\dfrac{D\vec{v_{{p/o'}_{pure~translation}}}}{Dt} $

what is wrong in the above derivation for the correct answer should be

$ \vec{a_p} = \vec{a_{o'}} + \vec{\alpha} \times \vec{r_{p/o'}} + 2 \omega \times \vec{v_{p/o'}} + \omega \times (\omega \times \vec{r_{p/o'}}) + \dfrac{D \vec{v_{p/o'}}}{Dt}  $

Comment: Are you sure about the last term? Has it to be with capital $D$?

Comment: Ya, the last term would be the component of relative acceleration, it will factor out as a(p/o')

Comment: But $\vec a_{p/o'}$ is the derivative, not the operator you have defined earlier. That's why I asked, the relative acceleration term doesn't appear. Anyway, I can derive the final formula with $d$ and I cannot with $D$.

Comment: The operator would convert the it to derevative., I think so. (v_(p/o), is to be the linear velocity of the point with respect to the moving​ reference frame,as if there were no angular velocity. Hence, I supposed that D/Dt(pure velocity |when rotation is ignored ) will give d/dt(velocity) and all other terms world reduce to zero.

Comment: Yes, it is the velocity with respect to the moving frame, but it's variation wrt time has two parts calculated for the inertial frame, not all but one terms vanish.

Comment: But D/Dt(v_p/o') has three parts, d/dt(v_p/o') = a_p/o', w X v_p/o' (I supposed this to be zero as v_p/o' is taken in the absence of rotation so, w = 0) and D/Dt(v_p/o').